# Strange behaviour of as.POSIXct

Tags: r

I'm having some troubles in understanding the behaviour of the function `as.Posixct` in R. It seems that something is happening around `02:00:00` of `2015-03-29`:

```
as.POSIXct("2015-03-29 02:57:53", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] NA

as.POSIXct("2015-03-29 01:57:53", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2015-03-29 01:57:53 CET"

as.POSIXct("2015-03-29 03:57:53", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2015-03-29 03:57:53 CEST"
```

To confirm this I've also tried the following code

```
time_seq_before <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2015-03-29 01:00:00"),
                       to = as.POSIXct("2015-03-29 01:59:59"),
                       by = 1)
length(time_seq_before)
[1] 3600

time_seq_after <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2015-03-29 03:00:00"),
                      to = as.POSIXct("2015-03-29 03:59:59"),
                      by = 1)
length(time_seq_after)
[1] 3600

time_seq <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2015-03-29 01:59:59"),
                to = as.POSIXct("2015-03-29 03:00:00"),
                by = 1)
length(time_seq)
[1] 2
time_seq
[1] "2015-03-29 01:59:59 CET"  "2015-03-29 03:00:00 CEST"
```

Is someone able to explain what is happening here? Thanks!

Comment: Daylight saving. That hour between 2 and 3 doesn't exist in the timezone you specified. Did you notice that before 2 it's CET and after 3 its CEST?

Comment: Thanks a lot! So it is better to specify the time in the UTC timezone, right? Something like
    as.POSIXct("2015-03-29 02:57:53", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")

Comment: That's an option. But I guess it really should be the timezone that's *correct* for the data you have